# Access Object values as an Associate array value

Tags: javascript

I have an associate array of :

```
  instrumentLookup: {
    hh: {label: 'Hi Hat', type: 'hh'},
    kd: {label: 'Kick Drum', type: 'kd'},
    o1: {label: 'other1', type: 'o1'},
    o2: {label: 'other2', type: 'o2'}
  }
```

I think that this structure is OK, but there may be a better way.

I am trying to create an instrument from this list by this function, where the param `addedInstrument` comes in as the same string as the label, so `hh`, `kd`, `o1`, ....:

```
addInstrument: function(addedIntrument) {
  console.warn(addedIntrument);
  var newLabel = this.defaults.instrumentLookup.addedIntrument.label;
  var newType = addedIntrument;
  console.warn(newLabel + ' ' + newType)
  // push it to the list
  // this.unusedInstruments.push({label:newLabel, type:newType});
}
```

There are a few questions in this, feel free to answer any or all or suggest an alternative:

- How do you access Object properties when the Object is the value of an associative array?
- Should I change it to an array[] of nested objects{type: {other attrs}} from an Associate array?

Comment: Remember that JavaScript objects are true [Associative Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (e.g. Maps that take strings as keys) and properties are not "indexed" as in PHP's definition of "associative array".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How do you access Object properties when the Object is the value of an associative array?**

It's pretty easy. You can do: `console.log(instrumentLookup.hh.label); //Hi Hat`

or `console.log(instrumentLookup.hh['label']); //Hi Hat`

> **Should I change it to an array[] of nested objects{type: {other attrs}} from an Associate array?**

You should use an array, if you need array behavior.

From comments:

> **then why doesn't instrumentLookup.addedIntrument.label work?**

`addedInstrument` is not a member of `instrumentLookup`, thus you can't use the `.` to access it (it will be undefined). Instead you need to do: `instrumentLookup[addedInstrument]`

> **I think that this structure is OK, but there may be a better way.**

You are already storing each instrument by the `type` parameter, so why duplicate it inside the object? Unless you have more than just Type and Label, you could simplify this even further by:

```
var instrumentLookup = { hh: 'High Hat', 
                         kd: 'Kick Drum', 
                         o1: 'Other1', 
                         o2: 'Other2'}
```

and rewrite your addInstrument method:

```
addInstrument: function(addedInstrument) {
  console.warn(addedIntrument);
   var inst = this.defaults.instrumentLookcup[addedInstrument];
   if(inst) {
     this.unusedInstruments.push({label:inst, type:addedInstrument});
   }
}
```

Comment: then why doesn't `instrumentLookup.addedIntrument.label` work?

Answer (score 3):

You need the *bracket notation* to dynamically access property names.

```
instrumentLookup[ addedIntrument ].label
```